# Create class objects from a database

Tags: c#, database, class

How do you create a new class object and add data to it from a database?

I have a table(tblCars) in a database and would like to loop through each row(Using sqldatareader?) and create a new object named after the primary key(Registration number), then add data to it from the other columns.

So instead of this:

```
carClass car1 = new carClass();
car1.registration = "RT11 HWY";
car1.make = "Ford";
```

It would be something like:

```
//connection and reader stuff
carClass <registration> = new carClass();
<registration>.registration = column1;
<registration>.make = column2;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some lightweight ORM for this kind of mapping. Take a look **[here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/persistence)**, there are many free solutions for this. There are also at least two made by Microsoft, **[LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)** and **[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)**

Comment: Also: see [Dapper Dot Net](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which powers this site :-)